# How to filter array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this array:

```
$scope.damageEvants =
    [
       {"id":2, "StartDate":21/05/2012, EndDate:null},
       {"id":3, "StartDate":null, EndDate:02/09/2014},
       {"id":4, "StartDate":null, EndDate:null},
       {"id":5, "StartDate":21/05/2012, EndDate:null}
    ];
```

I want to filter(remove) all objects from array where property startDate and EndDate are null.

The result after filtering:

```
$scope.damageEvants =
    [
       {"id":2, "StartDate":21/05/2012, EndDate:null},
       {"id":3, "StartDate":null, EndDate:02/09/2014},
       {"id":5, "StartDate":21/05/2012, EndDate:null}
    ];
```

I tried this:

```
$scope.damageEvants.filter(return item.StartDate!== null && item.EndDate !== null  )
```

But it seem to be wrong way.

How can filter `$scope.damageEvants` using filter function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$scope.damageEvants.filter(return item.StartDate!== null && item.EndDate !== null )
```

supposed to be

```
$scope.damageEvants.filter(function(item) {
     return item.StartDate!== null && item.EndDate !== null;
});
```

The `filter`

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.damageEvants = $scope.damageEvants.filter(function(item) {
     return item.StartDate!== null && item.EndDate !== null;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if either date is set.

```js
var array = [{ "id": 2, "StartDate": '21/05/2012', EndDate: null }, { "id": 3, "StartDate": null, EndDate: '02/09/2014' }, { "id": 4, "StartDate": null, EndDate: null }, { "id": 5, "StartDate": '21/05/2012', EndDate: null }],
    result = array.filter(function (a) {
        return a.StartDate || a.EndDate;
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

ES6 version

```js
var array = [{ "id": 2, "StartDate": '21/05/2012', EndDate: null }, { "id": 3, "StartDate": null, EndDate: '02/09/2014' }, { "id": 4, "StartDate": null, EndDate: null }, { "id": 5, "StartDate": '21/05/2012', EndDate: null }],
    result = array.filter(a => a.StartDate || a.EndDate);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

As Sushanth's answer indicates, `.filter()` expects to receive a function value, with that function returning a boolean value that determines if the current array member will be in the filtered array or not. Your code is passing filter a boolean value rather than a function value.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to splice the object in an angular.forEach loop.  This will actually remove the object from the original array rather than creating a new array.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh03zur4/

**Controller**

```
        function Controller($scope) {
      $scope.damageEvants = [{
        "id": 2,
        "StartDate": 21 / 05 / 2012,
        EndDate: null
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "StartDate": null,
        EndDate: 02 / 09 / 2014
      }, {
        "id": 4,
        "StartDate": null,
        EndDate: null
      }, {
        "id": 5,
        "StartDate": 21 / 05 / 2012,
        EndDate: null
      }];

      angular.forEach($scope.damageEvants, function(event) {
        if (!event.EndDate && !event.StartDate) {
          var idx = $scope.damageEvants.indexOf(event);
          $scope.damageEvants.splice(idx, 1);
        }
      });
    }
```

Another option based on Sushanth's answer would be to apply a filter in your ng-repeat list like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/qj7dz2eq/

**Controller**

```
$scope.filterEvents = function(item) {
  return item.StartDate !== null || item.EndDate !== null;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in damageEvants | filter:filterEvents">{{item.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Doing it either one of these ways prevents the same array being bound to the $scope twice.

Answer (score 1):

Can try like:

```
$scope.damageEvants = $scope.damageEvants.filter(function(obj) {
    return !(obj.StartDate === obj.EndDate && obj.StartDate === null);
});
```